# Access id of an ImageButton in onClickListener when there are dynamic no. of buttons in Android

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I have a tableLayout in Android and each row in the table has an ImageButton, a TextView and another ImageButton. The no. of rows is variable and I am generating the table programmatically at runtime.

I am setting id of the buttons to be same as row number by using `ImageButton.setId(i)`.

When the user clicks on any ImageButton, I want to be able to access its id in the onClickListener. Is there a way to do it? All answers on stackoverflow which I have seen regarding this involve a fixed no. of buttons and use a switch statement to find out the id. But since the no. of buttons is dynamic for me, this won't work for me.

Here's the code:

```
TableLayout tbl_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_layout);
for (int i=0; i<num_rows; i++) {

    TableRow tbl_row= new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tbl_row.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tbl_row.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
    //tbl_row.setBackground(R.drawable.border);

   if(i == 3)
        tbl_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    else
        tbl_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffd1"));

    tbl_row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setText("Some text goes here\New line.");


    ImageButton infoBtn = new ImageButton(this);
    infoBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_info);
    infoBtn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    infoBtn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    infoBtn.setMaxHeight(120);
    infoBtn.setMaxWidth(120);
    infoBtn.setId(i);
    //infoBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    ImageButton cameraBtn = new ImageButton(this);
    cameraBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
    cameraBtn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    cameraBtn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    cameraBtn.setMaxHeight(120);
    cameraBtn.setMaxWidth(120);
    cameraBtn.setId(i);

    tbl_row.addView(infoBtn);
    tbl_row.addView(tv);
    tbl_row.addView(cameraBtn);
    tbl_layout.addView(tbl_row, i);
}`
```

Comment: Where and on what view do you set the click listener?

Comment: @Simas, I set it on this View itself. I am planning to set in this Java Activity only. Something like cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @ Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                captureImage(); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<num_rows; i++) {

        TableRow tbl_row= new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tbl_row.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tbl_row.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
        //tbl_row.setBackground(R.drawable.border);

       if(i == 3)
            tbl_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
            tbl_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffd1"));

        tbl_row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setText("Some text goes here\New line.");


        ImageButton infoBtn = new ImageButton(this);
        infoBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_info);
        infoBtn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        infoBtn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        infoBtn.setMaxHeight(120);
        infoBtn.setMaxWidth(120);
        //infoBtn.setId(i);
        //infoBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
       infoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        ImageButton cameraBtn = new ImageButton(this);
        cameraBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        cameraBtn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        cameraBtn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        cameraBtn.setMaxHeight(120);
        cameraBtn.setMaxWidth(120);
        //cameraBtn.setId(i);
        cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        tbl_row.addView(infoBtn);
        tbl_row.addView(tv);
        tbl_row.addView(cameraBtn);
        tbl_layout.addView(tbl_row, i);
    }`
```

Comment: so, does this mean each button now has a separate onClickListener here and I simply do the processing based on 'i' inside this onClickListener ?

Comment: yes it is.And if your logic is bind to id then do it other wise no need to set id explicitly

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. It is working for now. :)